# Error loading default properties for object x-apple-eventkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

Help to create and save events it Icloud calendar. After saving i have error :

```
Error loading default properties for object x-apple-eventkit:///Alarm/p252 from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010 "(null)"



Error loading to-one relation originalAlarm from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010 "(null)"
```

My code:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFromater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSTimeZone * timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFromater setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFromater setDateFormat:@"Y-MM-d'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'"];
EKEventStore* evStore = [[EKEventStore alloc]init];
[evStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    EKEvent * event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:evStore];


    event.location=[dictionry valueForKey:@"location"];
    event.title = [dictionry valueForKey:@"eventName"];
    event.notes = [dictionry valueForKey:@"description"];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSString *str = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];


    event.startDate = [formatter dateFromString:[dictionry valueForKey:@"eventDate"]]; //[dictionry valueForKey:@"eventDate"];
    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];

    EKAlarm *ekAlarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-60];
    [event addAlarm:ekAlarm];

    RLMResults *object = [RealmUser allObjects];
    self.user= [object firstObject];
    event.calendar = [evStore calendarWithIdentifier:self.user.calendarIdentifier];

    EKRecurrenceEnd * end = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[dictionry objectForKey:@"endDateForReps"]intValue]]];
    EKRecurrenceFrequency  freq;
    NSString    *timeUntilForReps =[dictionry objectForKey:@"timeUnitForReps"] ;

    if ([timeUntilForReps isEqualToString:@"week"]) freq = EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly;
    else if ([timeUntilForReps isEqualToString:@"day"]) freq = EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily;
    else if ([timeUntilForReps isEqualToString:@"year"]) freq = EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly;
    else if ([timeUntilForReps isEqualToString:@"mounth"]) freq = EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly;

    NSInteger timeInterval = [[dictionry valueForKey:@"repeatInterval"] integerValue];
    EKRecurrenceRule * rule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc]initRecurrenceWithFrequency:freq interval:timeInterval end:end];
    [event setRecurrenceRules:@[rule]];


    [evStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
    if (error) NSLog(@"error");

}];
```

Comment: I have the same issue:
Error loading default properties for object x-apple-eventkit:///(null)/p102 from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010 "(null)"

Answer (score 0):

I had this set of errors while reading Calendar events:

```
Error loading default properties for object x-apple-eventkit:///Location/p1 from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)"
Error loading string title from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)"
Error loading default properties for object x-apple-eventkit:///Location/p1 from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)"
Error loading string address from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)"
```

Using `NSLog`, I determined that the messages were occurring while processing one particular event.

Based on the messages, I thought to log the event's location value and compare it to the other returned events. The value seemed to just be an empty string, though, and all the other events had empty strings, as well.

Further checking in the actual Calendar, I found that this particular event had a space or some non-visible character(s) in its location field (the deletion `x` was showing, but no characters seemed to be present). I removed the invisible character(s) by pressing the `x`: no more messages!

In this case, it wasn't my code causing the problem. However, the hints from the error messages led me to the solution. If I had been building events, I would've looked at my code around creating the Location property's data.

***Summary***:

- Note the property related to the error.
- Note the additional error message following the property error.
- Focus your troubleshooting in that area.